# Crystal Report ExportToStream Failing with Object Reference not set to an instance

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I have a very simple app that takes in No parameters in the attempt to return PDF.
The crystal Reports were authored using CR IX and I had to update the web service code to use Crystal Report for Visual studio 13.  I am able to set parameters, as well as being able to login and verify that login credentials are correct.

```
public string TestReport()
{
    try
    {
        var p = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Product", "03R95-01"),
            new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Product_Rev", "E-V001")
        };

         var reportParameters = new ParameterField[2];

        var rpt = InitializeReport("testReport", p);
        var s = rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        return "Stream exists";
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       return $"{ex.Message}|{ex.StackTrace}";
   }
}
```

The Initialize Report method is:

```
private ReportDocument InitializeReport(string svrId, string reportName, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> parameters)
{
    var uid = "userId";
    var pwd = "pwd";
    var svr = "serverId";
    var db = "DBNAME";

    var reportFolder = "c:\\CrystalTest\\ReportFolder";

    var reportFile = Path.Combine(reportFolder, $"{reportName}.rpt");
    var rpt = new ReportDocument
    {
        FileName = reportFile
    };
    rpt.Load(reportFile);

    var conInfo = new ConnectionInfo
    {
        UserID = uid,
        Password = pwd,
        ServerName = svr,
        DatabaseName = db
    };
    foreach (Table t in rpt.Database.Tables)
    {
        try
        {
            var loginInfo = t.LogOnInfo;
            loginInfo.ConnectionInfo = conInfo;
            t.ApplyLogOnInfo(loginInfo);
            if(!t.TestConnectivity())
            {
                throw new Exception($"{t.Name} failed login");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    rpt.VerifyDatabase();

    return rpt;
}
```

I have verified that an error is thrown when userid/pass combinations are incorrect.

I get the following error when I run this.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.| at
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext
> reqContext) at
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions
> options) at
> CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType
> formatType) at ICEWS4.maintenance.TestReport() in
> C:\CrystalTest.cs:line 724

Answer (score 0):

I learned of the fix.
I had CR for VS 13 SP 29.
The Runtime installed on the server was 13 SP 23
I was told by SAP to update to SP 30.
After updating my code, and installing the runtime, I was able to export to PDF as desired.